# No pthread_mutex_timedlock(…) in Xcode with -std=c++17 and CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++

Tags: c++, xcode, pthreads

I'm trying to include a c++ sdk in my Xcode project. The sdk is cross platform and compiles well with make CLI (has a relatively complex Makefile) on the same platform as my project (Darwin).
I'v got the sdk's samples working well with the compiled .a library too.

So I'v included all the sdk files in Xcode, linked with target, changed all the path of the headers' includes to match the project's structure, all went fine until the pthread_mutex_timedlock (from one sdk's source) came undefined.

I've set all the definition found in the makefile but the CXXSTANDARD used in sdk is C++11, I'm using C++17 because I need MetalCPP asking for C++17 minimum... But that shouldn't be a problem...

I probably need to change the compiler from default AppleClang to G++ that is used in SDK's makefile but even from terminal, using g++ links to clang…… and I've previously compiled the sdk with that clang… in terminal…

Any idea someone ?

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: */Users/maximus/Documents/Development/macOS/MetalCPP-RPLidar/rplidar-sdk/src/hal/locker.h:102:21 Use of undeclared identifier 'pthread_mutex_timedlock'*

Comment: in the same source *$pthread_mutex_unlock()* is used without any problem

Comment: This missing function is found on pubs.opengroup.org. So I even tried downloading from LLVM the libcxx-15.0.2 sources and included them in my project but it's not working … Though compiling the sdk with make is working, so some sources have this so missing function …

Comment: An "undeclared identifier" error means what it says: the specified identifier has not been declared in the scope where it is used.  That can be because a needed header has not been included, so make sure the source file where the error occurs performs an `#include <pthread.h>`.  If it does, then either Xcode's `pthread.h` fails to declare that function (though apparently it is present in the standard library), or it requires a feature selection macro to be defined, or something about the compilation options in effect is suppressing it.  Sorry to be so non-specific.

Comment: It is included by default by Xcode, but I've inserted the line in the respective source and the build fails the same way. I've already changed the c++ dialect to match the sdk's Makefile one, being std=c++11... and still undefined … the clang_cxx_library = libc++ …

Comment: Are you trying to *develop* the SDK in question, or just *use* it?  If the latter, then that should not require setting it up as an Xcode project itself.  You said its `make`-based build system builds it successfully, so go the next step and `make install`.  Then just use it as an ordinary external library in Xcode projects.

Comment: Well I've tried that approach, but without "make install"... I used the .a file I ended up with, included in search path and build phases, it worked just fine. But modifying the sdk and compiling it every time I will need it makes longer the trails&error repetition. It was convenient to compile it at the same time

Comment: I repeat: *if you are just using the SDK* then it makes sense to build it with its own build system.  That's the usual manner of usage of an SDK, and it implies not modifying it.  You don't need or want to rebuild it every time.  If you are modifying the SDK then that's a different story, and one that you might want to reconsider.  But if you persist with that then of course you do need some kind of development environment to do that in (but not necessarily an IDE such as Xcode, though that offers considerable convenience).

Comment: Considering I will have to adapt that sdk on an unsupported platform I preferred to get used with that approach. @JohnBollinger Thank you for your time